# Separating the values in an array into multiple variables in python

Tags: python

For example, if I have the array `orderids = ["gfau23Fd", "3278yis", "78gidtrh"]` and I have `numberoforders = 3`

How could I separate them to get `order1 = "gfau23Fd"`, `order2 = "3278yis"` and `order3 = "78gidtrh"`

Comment: Is there a reason you need separate variables `order1`, `order2`, etc?  Why can't you just use `orderids[0]`, `orderids[1]`, etc?

Comment: How do you plan to use these very specific variables in the rest of your program if you cannot know if they even exist? In other words: what *problem* are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: I agree with @usr2564301, it's unclear what you're asking, and this seems like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have a dynamic amount of orders and I wanted to have ordername = orderid pairs in a json file, what I am now doing is creating two lists, one with the order ids and other with the order names and correlate each using the index. i.e. if I need the order id for the 2nd item name I look for the 2nd item in the order ids list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating variables dynamically is rarely a good idea, and you should probably stick to using `orderids[0]`, `orderids[1]`, `orderids[2]` instead of `order1`, `order2`, `order3`. That said, here's a way to do what you ask:

```py
for i in range(numberoforders):
    exec('order{} = orderids[{}]'.format(i+1, i))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your example, you would use:

```
order1, order2, order3 = orderids
```

but if you are seeking to do this generically, you shouldn't. Use list indexing as @John Gordon suggests in his comment. Perhaps you can explain your problem in more detail, and there might be a better solution.

Comment: I suspect he wanted a generalized solution that would work for any number of orders.

Comment: I suspect you're right. I updated my answer with a note.

Comment: yeah, I am looking for a generalized solution but with a few modifications to my project list indexing would work. Thanks

Comment: you should definitely use list indexing